# Catch exception message from try catch statement to display on jquery dialog box in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dialog, messagebox

[try convert string to integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWXcv.png)

Dear masters,
I'm newbie about using jquery in asp.net and want to learn more. In my case, i need to display an exception from try catch statement using jquery dialog box rather than asp label. I started with Master Page project on asp.net c#.

Here is my Default.aspx codebehind:

```
protected void btnAsp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            labelMessage.Text = "Result: " + Convert.ToInt32(txbNumber.Text).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            labelMessage.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

In my Site1.Master i put JQuery script block:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

and i put this html div inside the Default.aspx

```
<div id="dialog" title="Alert">
    <p>
        JQuery dialog box goes here...
    </p>
</div>
```

My question is how to drive ex.Message in order to display to dialog above in jquery and how to catch this error event in page?

Many many thanks for all advices

Comment: You can use a property to store exception message and perform something like `var message = '<%= ErrorMessage %>'` in JS side. Then, pass that variable to the `alert`/`dialog` function content/parameter.

Comment: Or call a javascript function that opens the modal `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showScript", "showModal('" + ex.Message + "')", true);`

Comment: Great, this help me a lot!